# Build RoR from Spring MVC Java with separation of concerns

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring

I am used to building two separate apps for web-based applications.
The first web-app is a Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Hibernate Maven app, and this handles all the back-end work and logic to Get/Put/Delete data from the database.

The back-end has always had an architecture that looks like.

```
Entity.jar - stores all the hibernate entities per the database
Dao.jar - which has the Entity.jar and this seperate JAR does all the database work, to get, put, delete records into the database.   I believe I am using an Active record pattern.
Service.jar - contains Dao.jar so that the business logic here can make multiple calls to the database, and do other business logic calculations and functions and even make calls to third party systems.
```

ws.WAR -  the web-application which includes the Service.jar.  I can now have a whole collection of controllers that access the entire layer of business services.  The controllers have no business logic other than to server requests from any mobile or other web-app.

With the back-end being it's own service, I am now free to use that back-end for other third-party clients to access.  The back-end is free for any web-app that is built with either JQuery, Angular, React/Redux, etc.

So, It used to be when I first started with Spring that there was one WAR file that contained the back-end AND front-end.  With this the front-end and back-end were on one domain and I didn't have any CORS issues to contend with, but now they I have the front-end and back-end separated, I worked out that CORS issue.

So, NOW ... I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails and figure out why people love it, and why some people hate it.

I have rbenv installed, gems installed, ruby 2.5.0 installed, rails 5.1.5 installed, and working on the Aptana Eclipse Plugin so I can do my development work in Eclipse the way I always have.   This should be done fairly shortly.

Since I am a new to RoR, I am looking to build a RESTful back-end the way I did with Spring, and I was wondering if there were any articles out there on the Net to do this?   I am also curious if the front-end and back-end have to be combined like my old Spring apps, or if I can have a Ruby on Rails front-end, or is it a Ruby on Rails back-end?

It took a lot of time to find the best practices with Spring and RESTful development and then create a front-end to use that back-end.   I am looking to pick RoR fairly quickly based on the best practices I learned from Spring.

Thanks for any help.   And don't worry, I'll keep reading articles and playing around myself.   Thanks again!

Comment: *I am looking to pick RoR fairly quickly based on the best practices I learned from Spring.* Oh wait you're serious, let me laugh even harder. - Bender Bending Rodríguez

Comment: You might find [this website](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+restful+api) helpful.